# How to add X amount of year to YYYYMMDDHHMMSS format in bash?

Tags: bash, date

Bear with me I am not strong with `bash`. I have a date/time as in `YYYYMMDDHHMMSS` format such as `20031005000000`in string. I like to add one year to it. I've read `man date` but it was a bit hard to interpret what it says although I think I do have basic understanding of `-d` and `-s` option looking at many examples from WWW.

These are a few of many I read:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46411970/add-x-days-to-a-particular-date-in-bash
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25619923/bash-convert-date-to-timestamp
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18706823/how-to-increment-a-date-in-a-bash-script

So at the moment, I know how to add one year to current date.

```
myDatePlusOneYr=$(date -d "+365 days" '+%Y%m%d%H%M%S')
```

And I can add `one year` to date without having time segment (HHMMSS).

```
myDate="20031005"
date -d "$myDate +365 day"
Mon Oct  4 00:00:00 GMT 2004
```

However I have not found a way to add one year to a date/time format. When I tried with second option having with time segment, I get following error msg.

```
date: invalid date `20031005000000 +365 day'
```

I noticed `backtick` at the beginning of date/time and `single quote` at the end. I am not sure how to interpret the error msg. I'd appreciate your advice.

Update:
I found an answer for `invalid date`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4197606/how-to-convert-yyyymmddhhmmss-to-a-date-readable-by-date

Answer (score 4):

I might be over-simplifying it, but:

```
% expr 20091005000000 + 10000000000
20101005000000
```

Comment: I appreciate your reply. I didn't know about `expr` until now. I think I can parse out `year` and add `1` to it.

Comment: or only with bash: `d=20031005000000; declare -i x; x=$d+10000000000; echo $x`

Comment: The user below is correct that this approach doesn't work if the day is February 29th.

Answer (score 4):

You could just treat the string as a number:

```
#/bin/sh
date='20000229000000'
echo "$((date + 10000000000))"
```

that prints `20041005000000`. Of course it doesn't work correctly if your date happens to Feb 29th on a leap year, but that should be the only exception. You can deal with that by splitting the string to pieces and taking the leap day as a special case:

```
#!/bin/bash
date='20000229000000'
# assume it's correctly formatted
y=${date:0:4}
m=${date:4:2}
d=${date:6:2}
t=${date:8}

if [[ $m == 02 && $d == 29 ]]; then
        m=03
        d=01
fi

echo "$((y+1))$m$d$t"
```

In some shells, including Bash, the arithmetic treats numbers starting with zeroes as *octal*, but we're only doing arithmetic on the year, and it shouldn't have leading zeroes.

Answer (score 1):

I don't like this answer because it invokes 3 shell commands to do it, but it works. Start with `myDate="20031005010203"`

I assume you want 1 year added to that. The ugly way is to take it apart, treat the first 8 characters as a YYYYMMDD, add a year, and use the date command to format the result. It stitches the time back onto the time value. Notice that for my test data I use 20040229 (a valid leap year).

```
myDate="20040229010203"
datebit=$(echo $myDate | cut -c 1-8)
timebit=$(echo $myDate | cut -c 9-)
newdate=$(date -d "$datebit +1 year" +"%Y%m%d${timebit}")
echo "${newdate}"
```

The input was `20040229010203` and the output should be `20050301010203`.

So "one year from 01:02:03 on Feb 29 2004" is "01:02:03 on Mar 01 2005"

I tested this on ubuntu with the standard `date` command there.

Comment: Dammit. If I had just looked at @ikkachu's answer, I would see how to avoid most of these shell calls. But use date -d to do your math. Don't do special casing on february 29.